# Can action method add parameter to query string and continue normal flow without reloading the page/redirecting?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, query-string

I have a action method

-`ControllerName/Action?a=10`

I would like this action method to add `&b=5`(value of b is computed, 5 is for the example) parameter to URL, so it changes to:

-`ControllerName/Action?a=10&b=5`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Action(int a, int? b)
    {           
        if(!b.hasValue){
             //if b is not present in query string add it to query string
             RedirectToAction("Action", new object[] { a, b });
        }
        //more logic
       return View();
    }
```

but that will cause reloading of the page, and additional request in the network tab. Is there any better way to do it? Is there any way to avoid redirect at this stage?

**Disclaimer:** Passing it to the view by `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, `Model` or other ways doesn't solve the problem, becuase **I need it in query string itself for a 3rd party frontend library/component** that is out of my control and it reads the query string.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` sends an HTTP 302 response to the browser and tells it to load the new URL. So yes, it will cause a new HTTP request.

If the 3rd party library is JavaScript, then that is the only way you can do it from C#.

However, you can do it from your own JavaScript on the page without reloading the page by using `replaceState`:

```
var newurl = window.location + "&b=5";
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
```

However, notice that it's adding `&`, which assumes there is already another query parameter. If there was no query parameter yet, then it would need to be `?b=5`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is fundamentally impossible. The URI, including any query string constitutes a resource. Modifying the URI requires a new request for a new resource, which is going to cause the page to change in the browser. This just how the web works.